# Destroy promise without memory leak and don't execute any callbacks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, memory-leaks, q, angular-promise

I use `$q` to create deferred object. Normal use case like this:

```
deferred.promise.then(success_callback, error_callback)
```

When `deferred.resolve() / deferred.reject()`, it's fine, no memory leak because success_callback or error_callback was executed. But now I want to destroy the promise object, that means I don't want to call `deferred.resolve()` or `deferred.reject()`, without memory leak. How can I do that?

**EDIT:**
More clearly, I want to ignore the existent of the promise, I don't want `success_callback` or `error_callback` to be executed anymore. Yes, maybe I want to unregister callbacks.

Comment: can you do whatever memory cleanup tasks you run in resolve() on a no-side-effect then() call?

Comment: @dandavis: I don't want to execute `success_callback`. If I call `resolve()`, that callback is executed.

Comment: Wouldn't you be then "breaking your promise"? ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
delete deferred.promise
```

It is somewhat difficult to generate memory leaks in JS since it has automatic memory cleanup; the main way it happens is two objects referencing each other but which have no references to themselves outside of each other.

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. Because the promise object is still used to execute callbacks when deferred object resolve() or reject().

Comment: My mistake; I thought the delete keyword superceded JS's automatic memory trash-collecting. Given [Ben Nadel's approach](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2731-canceling-a-promise-in-angularjs.htm), I do not think there is an easy way to do it.